# Prisma Not Returning Created Related Records

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

i want to create a new graphql api and i have an issue that i am struggling to fix.

the code is open source and can be found at: https://github.com/glitr-io/glitr-api

i want to create a mutation to create a record with relations... it seems the record is created correctly with all the expected relations, (when checking directly into the database), but the value returned by the `create<YourTableName>` method, is missing all the relations.

... so so i get an error on the api because "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Meme.author.". i am unable to figure out what could be wrong in my code.

the resolver looks like the following:

```
...
const newMeme = await ctx.prisma.createMeme({
                author:  {
                    connect: { id: userId },
                },
                memeItems: {
                    create: memeItems.map(({
                        type,
                        meta,
                        value,
                        style,
                        tags = []
                    }) => ({
                        type,
                        meta,
                        value,
                        style,
                        tags: {
                            create: tags.map(({ name = '' }) => (
                                {
                                    name
                                }
                            ))
                        }
                    }))
                },
                tags: {
                    create: tags.map(({ name = '' }) => (
                        {
                            name
                        }
                    ))
                }
            });

            console.log('newMeme', newMeme);
...
```

that value of `newMeme` in the `console.log` here (which what is returned in this resolver) is:

```
newMeme {
  id: 'ck351j0f9pqa90919f52fx67w',
  createdAt: '2019-11-18T23:08:46.437Z',
  updatedAt: '2019-11-18T23:08:46.437Z',
}
```

where those fields returned are the auto-generated fields. so i get an error for a following mutation because i tried to get the author:

```
mutation{
  meme(
    memeItems: [{
      type: TEXT
      meta: "test1-meta"
      value: "test1-value"
      style: "test1-style"
    }, {
      type: TEXT
      meta: "test2-meta"
      value: "test2-value"
      style: "test2-style"
    }]
  ) {
    id,
    author {
      displayName
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone see what issue could be causing this?
(as previously mentioned... the record is created successfully with all relationships as expected when checking directly into the database).

Answer (score 0):

As described in the prisma docs the promise of the Prisma client functions to write data, e.g for the createMeme function, only returns the scalar fields of the object:

> When creating new records in the database, the create-method takes one input object which wraps all the scalar fields of the record to be
>   created. It also provides a way to create relational data for the
>   model, this can be supplied using nested object writes.
>
> Each method call returns a Promise for an object that contains all the
>   **scalar** fields of the model that was just created.

See: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/writing-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc6/#creating-records

To also return the relations of the object you need to read the object again using an info fragment or the fluent api, see: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#relations